Test Copy to clipboard on cypress
i'm working on a next.js project and i have to test the project on cypress, a part of the project i need to test is a button that copies a text to clipboard.
The copy to clipboard function;
  const copyToClipboard = (url: string) => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(url);
    toast({
      title: "Copied to clipboard",
      status: "success",
      duration: 2000,
      isClosable: true,
    });
  };

The code (I used chakra ui for the frontend)
<Box>
  <Heading>
    {item.title ? item.title : item.original_url + " - undefined"}
  </Heading>

  <Text>cxorz.vercel.app/{item.short_path}</Text>
  <Text>Long URL: {item.original_url}</Text>
  <IconButton
     icon={<CopyIcon />}
     aria-label="Copy URL"
     onClick={() => copyToClipboard(`${baseUrl}/${item.short_path}`)}
     data-id="copy-url"
  />
</Box>

this is how i tested the code
it("shortened link is visible to user", ()=>{
 
  cy.visit("/dashboard/links")
  cy.window().then(win => {
     cy.stub(win.navigator.clipboard, 'writeText').as('copy');
     cy.getByDataId("copy-url").click()
     cy.get('@copy').should('have.been.calledOnce', 'czors.vercel.app/google')
  })
})

but then i get the error "Trying to stub property 'writeText' of undefined"


I was able to resolve this with the help of a friend. first we created a mock for navigator.clipboard object and then stubbed the write test method
cy.window().then((win) => {
    if (!win.navigator.clipboard) {
        win.navigator.clipboard = {
          writeText: () => {}
        };
      }
    cy.stub(win.navigator.clipboard, "writeText").resolves().as('clipboardWrite');
  });
cy.getByDataId("copy-url").click();
cy.get('@clipboardWrite').should(
    'have.been.calledOnceWith',
    'https://cxorz.vercel.app/search',
)

and it worked

